# Architecture for secure local services for an HTML5 app

Tags: .net, node.js, html, jakarta-ee

I have users that want a multi-device app, with complete offline functionality.

Some of the data that needs to be stored offline is super duper hyper secret, and cannot be safely stored in HTML 5 local storage. Also some of the functionality is very complex (complex financial scenario modelling and visualisations)

My current idea for a solution to this is an HTML5 app with all relevant functionality against server side REST services, and then developing a local service layer for specific devices which stores and secures the super duper hyper secret data.

The app would then perform REST calls to the server when it is online, and when it is offline it would call those same interfaces on a local server.

The local server would upload data to the remote server (using those same calls) when it is online.

Questions:
1.) Any suggestions for javascript frameworks that could ease this setup?
2.) What back-end app architecture would work? I am torn between something enterprisey and easy with strong cryptography support (.NET or Java) vs something like node with mongodb.

Comment: Just to be clear, the intention is to tell the user community that they get a complete omni-device app for online right off the bat, with selected platforms enabled for offline processing (maybe Windows PC at first, followed by Android tabs or IPads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine you are thinking about something like a hybrid app that talks to a local version of the server when no remote version is available, but that to the extent that's possible you'd like to keep the local and remote servers as identical as possible.

If that's what you're thinking, then you'll need to embed a server in your application, and if it's a hybrid application then node is probably the only game in town. See this blog post: http://modernweb.com/2015/03/19/develop-an-ios-application-with-node-js-and-cordova/ and this project: http://jxcore.io/.  This is going to be pretty bleeding edge, but probably doable. You'll just hit the local server when the network is unvailable and  proxy requests to the remote server when the network is.

Let's just stick to the secure storage aspect for the moment.  If you are planning to store the server side data in a SQL database, then I might recommend using a version of SQLite that supports encryption on the client, like https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/. It runs on all platforms.

If you want to use something that looks like Mongo, there's minimongo, a project backed by the meteor folks that runs client side, is backed by local storage, and can sync up when the network is available: https://github.com/mWater/minimongo.

Otherwise, you're probably going to create a native app for each platform. I haven't been keeping up with all the java news on this front, but there should be plenty to choose from. On the .net side there's http://xamarin.com/, which will let you target almost every platform.

If you go this route, you may lose the HTML 5 capability.  But that might be a good thing in terms of user experience. You'll wind up do something clever like call your service layers directly when the network isn't there, and call them remotely when it is. Read up on this to get a flavor for what'll need to be done: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html, even though the technology may not be directly applicable.

As I mentioned below, I'm currently high on all things node and javascript, and upon reflection I'm thinking the risk to both approaches is probably similar.  As you say, it'll come done to the resources you have available and whether the lack of HTML 5 is a deal breaker.

***Upon further reflection and research, I think you should evaluate something like https://www.meteor.com/  which might just handle all your use cases (kind of rolling together all the pieces described above.***

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for those links Robert, I appreciate it. I suppose the big question is going to be what skills my organisation has available, which will inform whether I want to go with node locally or maybe Java.  I am definitely going to be checking out jxcore and sqlcipher

Comment: It's true, you'll have to decide.  I'm really high on all things javascript  lately, but if you have a room full of java developers...  My gut tells me that the risk of the java approach might be a tiny bit smaller.